# Use hasAttribute in DomParser

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, domparser

I use in my Nodejs script the function hasAttribute to check whether this exists.

```
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

            var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(dataRegelWerk);
            var allok = false;
            var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TCafe");
            if (x.length != 0)
            {
               //Existiert Attribute prüfen
                if(x.hasAttribute('initvalue') == true){
                    if(x.getAttribute('initvalue') == '1'){
                        if(x.hasAttribute('type') == true){
                            if(x.getAttribute('type') == 'int'){
                                allok = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But node tell me the whole time that hasAttribute is not a function. I am confused about this message because in all docs and references this function is available. Do I miss something?
Alternative ways?

Comment: You are getting a collection from "getElementsByTagName". You should try with x[0].hasAttribute("initvalue").

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName()` ***returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name***, you have to use the specific *index*. Since `hasAttribute()` returns boolean value you can shorten the condition:

```
if(x[0].hasAttribute('initvalue')){......
```

and

```
if(x[0].getAttribute('initvalue') == '1'){.......
```